# Retrieve product custom field values in product page custom fields

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce

**What I have ?**

A single product page showing customs fields to be filled before add item to cart. I have added a button which should put all the values in the custom fields in a text file and save it without reloading the page.

[image]

**What is my code?**

in simple.php

```
<input type="submit" id="ajax-order-btn" class="button" value="Place Order via AJAX" />
```

in functions.php

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'ajax_call_place_order');
function ajax_call_place_order() {
    if ( is_product() ){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(document).on("click", "#ajax-order-btn" ,function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var data = {
                    'action': 'ajax_order',
                };

                $.post('<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data);
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_order_callback_wp');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_order_callback_wp' );
function ajax_order_callback_wp() {
    $custom_fields_value = ***What Should Go Here***
    file_put_contents(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/orders/AJAX_TEST.txt', $custom_fields_value);
}

?>
```

Comment: So, you're trying to send values from the WooCommerce form to your `ajax_order_callback_wp` function but you don't know how to do that, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, do you know how ?

Comment: Sure, but I'll need more to help you out. You'll need to be able to select the `<form>` element to get the data from the form. Could you include that element in your question?

Comment: I think this what you mean. `<form class="cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're not sending anything to your `ajax_order_callback_wp` function. To do this you must get the values from the form, by selecting the form and extracting the values.

Instead of listen for the button click, listen for the `submit` event on the form. Preventing this default behavior will stop the form from reloading the page.

Now the `$.post` function is responsible for sending data to your backend, but it currently only gets an object with `'action': 'ajax_order'` sent with it. It needs the data from the form as well.

jQuery has a function called [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/#serialize) which can be called on a form element to extract the data from the form. Pass that form data to the `data` object. Now your form data is included.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $form = $('form.cart');

  $form.on("submit" ,function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      'action': 'ajax_order',
      'data': $form.serialize()
    };

    $.post(<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>, data);
  });
});
```

On the receiving end you can now extract the value by reading out the global `$_POST` variable. This variable is available in every function and will contain values if something has been sent using the POST method. In your case you used the jQuery `$.post`, so `$_POST` is the way to go.

Because the property on the object is called `data` you'll need to access that property on the `$_POST` array to see what the values are.

```php
function ajax_order_callback_wp() {
  // If data is there, use it, otherwise use an empty array.
  $data = $_POST[ 'data' ] ?? [];

  file_put_contents(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/orders/AJAX_TEST.txt', $data );
}
```

If you need to know what `$data` contains, then you could send a response back to the client with the contents of `$data` to inspect it on the frontend. Add this to end of the PHP `ajax_order_callback_wp` function.

```php
wp_send_json_success( $data );
```

And this to your `$.post` function in JavaScript.

```js
$.post(<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>, data, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I managed to do it with your code thank man. Just "submit" needed to be changed to "click", otherwise the page will reload and I won't have results as seems the ajax_order_callback_wp function will not get called. Thanks again.